# Pentaho XML to Excel Delimiter

Tags: xml, pentaho, delimiter

In Pentaho Spoon, I extracted values from an XML and the output is exactly as shown below:
"

```
    Power On

  55555ZA
  1
  2
  L5555544444
  0
  FADB
  KIANO
  102
"
```

I want to split these values to different headers. I tried "Split Fields" but I don't know the exact delimiter to use.
What should I do? Should I try a string operation?

Comment: What should be the delimiter? Can you add the result?

Comment: The result should be comma separated:
"Power On, 55555ZA,1,2, L5555544444,0, FADB, KIANO,102"

Answer (score 0):

If there is a new line you can try ${line.separator} as delimiter.

But honestly, this looks like the XML inout step is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit twisted but it worked.

1. I first did a string operation where I trimmed both sides and then removed Line feeds.
2. Then I replace "  " (two spaces) with a "," (comma) using "Replace in String".
3. I then replaced ",,," (three commas) with one "," (comma).
4. Now the only problem was two commas ",," which i replaced with one ","
5. After this I was getting my desired output which was comma seperated. I could easily split the fields using a "Field Seperator" with delimiter as ",".

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9gS4.png)

I would appreciate a more refined and proper method rather than the above hack I just did.